# Current transformer burden rating

Tags: transformer

Is it true that a burden lower than the CT rated burden will results in CT measurement inaccuracy that would exceed the CT accuracy class limit.
So, a CT percentage error matches the nameplate CT percentage error ONLY when the actual burden is equal to the CT rated burden.
The total burden on the CT is that of the relays, meters, connecting leads and the burden due to the resistance of the secondary winding of the CT.
In other words, if a CT rated burden is .2 Ω, but, the actual burden was 0.3 Ω OR if the actual burden 0.1 Ω, there will be higher error in its measurement even when the CT is operating at its rated current.

Is this true or not?

Answer (score 1):

The series resistance of a CT secondary will influence the voltage seen across the burden resistor, as will the magnetic field in the core, if it approaches saturation.  The CT itself will have been characterised at a known burden load, and so anything that differs significantly can be expected to affect the output voltage, perhaps not by very much but it is preferable to use the value specified in the datasheet unless you have good reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that a burden lower than the CT rated burden will results in CT measurement inaccuracy that would exceed the CT accuracy class limit.

Yes, it is.

A burden resistor (R<sub>burden</sub>) is used to convert a reduced current (e.g. for a 2000:1 CT) to a voltage so that it can be measured and/or processed by a microcontroller or a microprocessor. Decreasing or increasing R<sub>burden</sub> will result in a decreased or increased output voltage (V<sub>meas</sub>).

Increasing R<sub>burden</sub> may result in **non-linearity** because of the Volt-seconds limitation of the core (i.e. the limit of the output voltage for a given frequency), or even saturate the core. Increasing further or leaving open (i.e. R<sub>burden</sub> = infinity) leads to the breaking of the insulation between primary and secondary.

Decreasing R<sub>burden</sub> results in decreased output voltage. Again, because of the Volt-seconds limitation, if the frequency becomes too low then the core may saturate. If the core saturates then the output voltage will be limited and far beyond the expected, and thus the result is inaccuracy.